# Java 7 JDK wont uninstall

Tags: java, minecraft

I installed jdk 7 but minecraft didnt work. I tried uninstalling it in many ways but it was still on the machine and minecraft still didnt work. Does anynone know how to fix this?
My ubuntu version is 12.04 LTS. Ive searched the internet and i cant find anything that works. whenever i try something new java 7 still appears in dash home and minecraft still gets black screen. after trying a few new things minecraft wont even open
 i tried sudo apt-get purge, apt-get remove and a lot of other commands.i cant quite remember the ppa but i think it was http://www.launchpad.net/webupd8/java7
that might not be correct but thats what i remember. i also tried to mod minecraft by deleting meta-inf and adding minecraft forge.

Comment: does minecraft require javaws ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an hidden hint about openjdk-6-jre working without problem with minecraft
(see comments) :

[Minecraft in jdk 1.7.0_u2 x64](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100751/minecraft-in-jdk-1-7-0-u2-x64)

Comment: openjdk6 used to work fine until i upgraded to java 7. openjdk6 is not the problem oraclejava 7 is.

Comment: @linuxguy you upgraded to java 7 ?! - no new-package-installation of java 7 ? here are 2 links where is more to find : http://askubuntu.com/questions/117543/how-to-remove-oracle-jdk http://java.com/en/download/help/linux_uninstall.xml

Comment: either option did not worked for me :(

Comment: You have then to clean your filesystem manually - or a trick would help - you could install netbeans (package without jdk !!! http://netbeans.org ) - when you have luck, netbeans finds your jdk-installation and proceed with installation. After reboot you can remove netbeans and then it would remove jdk-7 too ? - am not sure if this works. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-7-netbeans-install-433844.html

Comment: @linuxguy here is some more present as solution: http://askubuntu.com/questions/84483/how-to-completely-uninstall-java